# Filling an array with core data attributes

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to fill my array.

```
var weights = []
```

with attributes from an NSManaged object. My core data relationship is like follows Client<-->>Assessment. I have a 'weight' attribute within assessment and I would like to fill my array with these values which are strings. My variable:

```
var client: Client! = nil
```

successfully retrieves the specific client that I have selected, but I do not know how to fill my array with the values of that particular client's assessment attribute called 'weight'. I've only gotten as far as...

```
client.assessment.count
```

which successfully shows me the number of assessments the client has, but how to I access the weight attribute of each of those assessments for my array?

My managed object classes for Client and Assessment are as follows:

Client.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Client)
class Client: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var assessment: NSSet
}
```

Assessment.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Assessment)
class Assessment: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var weight: String
    @NSManaged var client: Client
}
```

Can anyone help me know how to do this?

UPDATE:
Screenshot of the error I get with @Wain 's answer. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use KVC to get the weights in a set:

```
var weights: NSSet! = client.assessment.valueForKey("weight")
```

And then you can extract an array from that by sorting or just requesting all objects.

Comment: When I do that I get that my viewcontroller.type "does not have a member named 'client'"

Comment: You said you have `client.assessment.count` working? Where is the error exactly?

Comment: On the weights variable. I'll upload a screenshot.

Comment: Have you defined both of the variables in the class? You should be doing the `client.assessment.valueForKey` part in a function

Comment: Ok, I got it. One thing that isn't working for me though is that I need the weights array to be an array of int's, right now it's an array of strings from what I understand since 'weight' attribute is stored to CoreData in strings from text fields. How would I make it an array of int's?

Comment: use `valueForKey` again with `integerValue`

Comment: If I create "assessmentWeights" variable and fill it with my weight attribute like var assessmentWeights: AnyObject = client.assessment.valueForKey("weight") then fill my original 'weights' variable like weights = assessmentWeights.integerValue is that what you're talking about? I get 'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'NSArray' error. (Sorry I'm so illiterate! ;))

Comment: weights = assessmentWeights.valueForKey("integerValue")

Comment: Hmm. Then I get "cannot convert the expression's type () to type 'string'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73152/discussion-between-wain-and-leighton).